# How to add assetbundle js/css add only in one page in yii2?

Tags: yii2, assetbundle

I have added fullcalendar js/css in vendor/bower folder. I want to add this into just one page.

I read abt AssestBundle on this link - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

But this add in all the pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Yii 2 framework asset bundles is recommended way of working with js / css. It's not limited to just adding to all pages. You can use it only in specific view.

Example of asset bundle for `JsTree` plugin:

```
<?php

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class JsTreeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower_components/jstree/dist';

    public $js = [
        'jstree.min.js',
    ];

    public $css = [
        'themes/default/style.min.css',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

In this example, `@bower_components` alias is used, in order to get it working you also need to register it in application bootstrap file (in advanced application template this file is `common/config/bootstrap.php`):

```
Yii::setAlias('bower_components', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/bower_components');
```

Then, in view where you need to use it, call `register()` method of this asset bundle and pass current view:

```
use backend\assets\JsTreeAsset;

...

JsTreeAsset::register($this);
```

The files in default asset bundle (`AppAsset`) which included in application templates are loaded in every view because it's registered in application layout and layout is applied to all views.